# How to fix 'the arguments to the parameterized interface are not valid' error of IDL file in WinRT?

Tags: winrt-async, c++-winrt

I'm getting "the arguments to the parameterized interface are not valid" error when trying to write IDL file for my Windows Runtime Component class.

The RunAsync() function returns winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation in my header and I translated it to winrt.Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/winrt-cref/winrt-type-system states that UInt32 is "fundamental type" and "[WinRT fundamental types] are permitted to appear in the argument list for a parameterized type".

```
//ConnectTask.idl
namespace NOVAShared
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass ConnectTask
    {
        ConnectTask();
        winrt.Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<UInt32> RunAsync();
    };
}
```

```cpp
//ConnectTask.h
namespace winrt::NOVAShared::implementation
{
    struct ConnectTask : ConnectTaskT<ConnectTask>
    {
        ConnectTask() = default;

        static winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<uint32_t> RunAsync();
    };
}
```

Is my syntax wrong? I've found some random examples of IDL files and it seems right...

Comment: I believe the error message is misleading. The real issue is, that you are referencing the wrong type in the IDL. It should be `Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`. The `winrt` namespace is where the projected types live.

Comment: thank you! that worked. Post it as answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message of the MIDL compiler is a fair bit misleading. When you compile the following IDL file

```
namespace NS
{
    runtimeclass MyType
    {
        foo<UInt32> bar();
    }
}
```

you'll get this error message:

> ```
> error MIDL5023: [msg]the arguments to the parameterized interface are not valid [context]: foo
> ```

However, it's not the argument that's invalid. It's the parameterized type (`foo`) that's unknown. In your case that's `winrt.Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`. A type with that name does not exist. The Windows Runtime type name is `Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation` instead (which gets projected into the `winrt` namespace in C++/WinRT, i.e. `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation`).

To fix the issue, use the following IDL file:

```
//ConnectTask.idl
namespace NOVAShared
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass ConnectTask
    {
        ConnectTask();
        Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<UInt32> RunAsync();
    };
}
```

Note that if you want a static class member, you will have to use the `static` keyword in IDL.